# Не отображается всплывающее окно для авторизации Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, драйвер

Есть много информации в Интернете о том, как авторизироваться во всплывающем окне. Но только все они добираються до элементов через HTML-теги и блоки.

В моем случае такой возможности нет, либо я не до конца использую силую фреймворка.
У меня не отображается всплывающее окно в HTML-коде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

url = 'http://192.168.2.105/'
PATH_TO_WEBDRIVER = f'{os.getcwd()}/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH_TO_WEBDRIVER)
driver.get(url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это очень похоже на basic авторизацию, а с условием того, то вы обращаетесь к ip адресу в локальной сети, то скорее всего это сетевое устройство, а так, что с 90 % уверенностью, могу сказать, что вам поможет следующие
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/basic-http-authentication#pass-username-and-password-in-the-url

Comment: Я пытался использовать этот способ, но вводил не тот пароль.... Я вводил рандомный пароль ожидая, что увижу щас что-то "пароль не верный", а нужно было просто ввести правильный и мне сразу загрузилась бы страница. Спасибо